# NeweyWest - argument of length zero

Tags: r, standard-error

Hi there i'm new in R so here's my problem:

I am trying to reproduce a master thesis topic working with a fama french model for asset pricing concerning cryptocurrencies. Basically i got the forumla:

r=beta1*rm+beta2*SMB+beta3*HML

I got my calculations for the rm, SMB and HML (all vectors within 364 entries) and my historic returns r within 364 entries. (rm named CRIX, referring to a benchmark) 
I now checked if i could just use the lm function for my regression (which works fine) but the test for heteroscedasticity showed i need to use robust standard errors, so I'd use the NeweyWest function but allways get the error:

```
Error in if (ncol(x) == 1) { : argument is of length zero
```

---

```
 bitcoin <- lm(formula = returns_daily[,"bitcoin"]~CRIX+SMB+HML)

summary(bitcoin)

Call:
lm(formula = returns_daily[, "bitcoin"] ~ CRIX + SMB + HML)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.218119 -0.028217  0.000865  0.029360  0.252865 
Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.005456   0.002867   1.903 0.057856 .  
CRIX         0.193845   0.051950   3.731 0.000221 ***
SMB          0.038500   0.034388   1.120 0.263637    
HML         -0.067920   0.034054  -1.994 0.046856 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
Residual standard error: 0.05312 on 360 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.0532,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.04531 
F-statistic: 6.743 on 3 and 360 DF,  p-value: 0.0001952

coeftest(bitcoin)
t test of coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.0054561  0.0028673  1.9029 0.0578556 .  
CRIX         0.1938453  0.0519501  3.7314 0.0002212 ***
SMB          0.0385002  0.0343879  1.1196 0.2636373    
HML         -0.0679199  0.0340543 -1.9945 0.0468558 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

> coeftest(bitcoin,vcov=NeweyWest(bitcoin))
Error in if (ncol(x) == 1) { : argument is of length zero

NeweyWest(bitcoin)
Error in if (ncol(x) == 1) { : argument is of length zero
```

My input vectors all got the same length and i got no missing values so i don't really understand why my NeweyWest-Test wouldnt work. Any recommendations on how to track my error?

Comment: I can't reproduce  your error on a test data set. To get help on this you'll probably need to create a minimal reproducible example, for instance you could post some of your data using `dput()`.

Answer (score 0):

Just encountered the same error, but was lucky to find a solution to it, which is to provide the data to the `lm` function using the `data` argument. Leaving this here for the future generations, as, I guess, such a question could hardly not have expired for the author in 7-month time.